Error when doing git push heroku main "fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/appname.git/'"
The complete error:
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/appname.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (*.parasense-dev.net) does not match target host name 'git.heroku.com'

It was working fine, before I did a rollback on the heroku website and now I get this error  trying to do a push from cli.
I tried removing and adding it again as so:
git remote rm heroku
heroku git:remote -a appname

I also tried heroku keys:add and even deleted my repository locally and did again but to no avail.
